# I can't center div using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

So I’ve tried centering a `div`, but only the children get effected.

What am I doing wrong?

Here’s my current code:

```js
<div class="card">
  <img src="images/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Here’s what’s actually happening:

[image: Image example 1]

Answer (score 0):

Use the flexbox on the parent, not on the div you want to center:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the HTML structure (not inserting parent), you could just use the horizontal margin auto like this:

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="images/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**EDIT: OP wants to center it both vertically and horizontally.**
If you want to do that, you need to modify the most top parent as well (the `<body>` tag) and make its height 100%, like this:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still does not work the card is at top of sceen

Comment: @yaseenomeira you should have made it clear that you want it to center it both vertically and horizontally, I edited my answer

Answer (score -1):

The properties `justify-content` and `align-items` were applied for the children of `.card`. If you want to **center** the `.card` you will have to set the display property to flex for the parent of .card. or if the `.card` has a fixed width which in your case it has, you can also set the `margin-x:auto` on the `.card`, by doing so it will be aligned at the **center** of it's parent container. Hope I was able to make you understand.